# How should I select a correct answer to my question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answers

I've asked a question here:

[How should I implement side-scrolling level design?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20697/how-should-i-implement-side-scrolling-level-design/20740#20740)

I have received two answers I think are correct. 
One answer seems to be the most accurate for game development in general, the other is more accurate to my specific situation. 
However, the latter answer is more accurate to my situation because the poster picked up that I'm programming in Greenfoot based on an screenshot I had uploaded.

Is it better to mark the former answer as correct because in general circumstances it is more correct, and because I didn't mention Greenfoot in the question.
Or is it better to select the latter answer because it answers the question in a very specific way relating to my problem in Greenfoot, even though I didn't mention Greenfoot in the original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Greenfoot part should have been in your question in the first place, I have corrected that.

I'd say that you should accept the answer that helped you the most, even if there are other answers that seems to have a broader appeal. For two reasons:

The question may seem broader, but practically it could very well be relevant mostly to people in your exact situation, while the more academic answer may seem nicer to most of us it is probably a subject that is plenty covered already. To those actually experiencing the situation the realization that they are working with a shitty framework may be a lot more valuable than general optimization advice.

The answers that go an extra step to fit the exact situation of the asker are often somewhat overlooked, give 'em some credit for the work.

You still can and should award multiple upvotes if there are multiple good answers. Placing an accept doesn't mean that is the final truth, readers should know that.